# ETL data from MySQL to SQL Server data warehouse

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I need to implement ETL jobs from MySQL to SQL Server.

Reporting platform is using on-premises Microsoft Reporting Service and Analysis Service and MSSQL.

How can I ETL data from the production database which is running on MySQL Amazon RDS to MSSQL on-premises? Which tools are available for ETL data on a regular basis from LOTP (AWS MySQL) to OLAP (MSSQL)?